# Unable to upload file using "InvokeHTTP" processor in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to upload a file using "InvokeHTTP" processor in Apache Nifi
Content-Type : multipart/form-data

Getting 500 response.
"message":"RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for multipart"

Please share if anybody has an solution for this.
I face issue with multipart/form-data only in "InvokeHTTP" Processor?

Comment: Add the screenshot of your InvokeHTTP processor configuration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.